# Print formatting by the longest string iterable in a list

Tags: python

I have two lists

```
l1 = ['aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa','bb'] 
l2 = ['FY', 'EY']
```

I want to iterate over both lists (always identical in length) and print each iterable separated by a number of tabs.

For example:

```
for x,y in zip(l1,l2):
    print(x,'\t'*3,y)


aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa            FY
bb           EY
```

However, I want the print to be tabbed by the longest element in the list so the print has a standardized format:

```
print(formatted_print_tabs)


aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa            FY
bb                           EY
```

I've spent some time trying to figure this out and I'm left scratching my head.

Comment: You'll have to parse once to get widths, and again to do the prints. Because the widths are arbitrary, you may want to use spaces.

Comment: thanks @KennyOstrom I had taken a similair approach and tried replacing my variables with themselves using `re.sub` + the diff in white space but it felt wrong (and was about 5 lines of code)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can compute the maximum width first and then use `ljust` to fill the strings:

```
width = max(map(len, l1))
for x, y in zip(l1, l2):
    print(x.ljust(width), y, sep='\t')
```

Comment: `print(x.ljust(width), y, sep='\t'*3)`